# Glycosidation and glycosylation

Tags: cell-biology

I read somewhere that the function of Golgi bodies is glycosylation and glycosidation. What is the difference between the two? I searched google but it gives complex answers.

Comment: “I read somewhere” is not adequate for this list. Unless you can tell us where and either cite in full we cannot assess the accuracy or examine the context of your assertion.

Answer (score -1):

Glycosylation is a controlled process that involves a carbohydrate being attached to a hydroxyl or other functional group of another molecule. I think you meant to say glycation instead of glycosylation, and that is a random process that involves free sugars attaching to proteins.

https://www.neb.com/faqs/2015/04/10/what-is-the-difference-between-glycosylation-and-glycation

Comment: Welcome to [biology.se]. Can you please add some references to support your answer? References are useful for users to verify the answer and for understanding the topic better.

Comment: Sure, my bad. https://www.neb.com/faqs/2015/04/10/what-is-the-difference-between-glycosylation-and-glycation

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Please [edit] your answer to include it. Comments are only meant for temporary suggestions/requesting clarifications.